# Event Monitoring Analytics Studio missing Salesforce Data option in Create new Dataset

Tags: event-monitoring, crm-analytics

We've licensed Shield and this comes with Analytics Studio included.  By following the [Trailhead for Event Monitoring Analytics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring_analytics/event_monitoring_analytics_add), when you create a new dataset, you should see three options

- `CSV File`
- `Salesforce data`
- `External Data`

But I see only **CSV File**.  How do I see the other options?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem only occurs if you turned on Event Monitoring / CRM Analytics before Winter 20 (which was true in our org). See [SFDC Help Enable Data Sync and Connections](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_integrate_enable_replication.htm&type=5)

Resolve this by going to `Settings > Analytics > Settings` and checking the box `Enable Data Sync and Connections`.

- It takes a very long time for the Save to occur and you may see an error about a developer api name that you can ignore. You may need to refresh the page a few times to verify that the change "stuck".

[image]

Once complete, if you create a New Dataset, you will see the expected options:

---

[image]